# Redirect and rows count in filename

Tags: terminal, cron, io-redirection, wc

I try to name a file with rows count in a `crontab` :

```
* * * * * ~/script > "~/targetfile-$(rows-count).csv"
```

I can do :

```
* * * * * ~/script > "~/targetfile-$(~/script | wc -l).csv"
```

But I think I can do much better and not execute script twice.

Can you help me ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the output of your script to a temporary file, count the number of lines in that file and move the file to a new name:

```bsh
t=$(mktemp) && len=$("$HOME/script" | tee -- "$t" | wc -l) && mv -- "$t" "$HOME/targetfile-$len.csv"
```

If you are not using GNU `wc`, you may get whitespace characters at the start or end of the value in `$len`.  You would then need to strip these out:

```bsh
t=$(mktemp) && len=$("$HOME/script" | tee -- "$t" | wc -l) && mv -- "$t" "$HOME/targetfile-$(( len + 0 )).csv"
```

I run `"$HOME/script"` only once here and save the output to a temporary file (`$t`) and, at the same time (courtesy of `tee` for duplicating the data), count the number of lines in the output. The temporary file is then moved to the new name.

I would probably put this in a separate script and schedule that, rather than scheduling that whole list  in my crontab.

The script could look like

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp) &&
length=$("$HOME/script" | tee -- "$tmpfile" | wc -l) &&
mv -- "$tmpfile" "$HOME/targetfile-$(( length + 0 )).csv"
```

Comment: Note that some `wc` implementations add blanks before and after the number, so your *`${length##*[[:blank:]]}`* would expand to nothing there. A common idiom to avoid issues with those blanks is to use `$(( $(wc -l) ))` (or `$(( $(wc -l) +0 ))` to still get 0 with those shells where `$(( $empty ))` doesn't do it already).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ouch. Thanks!

Comment: The `+0` would not be needed in `$(( len + 0 ))` as `$((len))` is required to expand to 0 if `$len` is empty and anyway `$(( len ))` by itself is valid syntax. But `$(( len ))` when `$len` is not a decimal number is unspecified per POSIX and wouldn't work in `bosh` for instance with `len=" 1 "`. `$(( $len + 0 ))` is fine as the `$len` is expanded first and `$((  1  +0 ))` (or `$(( +0 ))` when `$len` is empty are valid syntax. I'd do `len=$(( $(wc -l...) +0 ))` here. Though with `... | wc -l` as opposed to `wc -l < ...`, the output is unlikely to be empty and the `+0` could be omitted.

Comment: Great, mktemp and tee were the key. Is there a reason to use -- with mv ?

Comment: @JCH77 It's just a precaution in the very unlikely event that `$t` starts with a dash. Note that I forgot this with `tee` (fixed now).

Answer (score 2):

Here, you could tell `cron` to use `zsh` to interpret the command line and do:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
* * * * * TMPPREFIX=~/.; (){ mv -- $1 ~/targetfile-$(($(wc -l < $1))).csv; } =(~/script)
```

That is use the `=(...)` form of process substitution to store the output of the script in a tempfile (as a hidden file in `~` instead of `/tmp` so the `mv` just does a rename), here passed as an argument to an anonymous function which renames it to the target file name.

Or to feed the output of the script to both the tempfile and `wc -l` at the same time:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
* * * * * TMPPREFIX=~/.; (){ ~/script >&1 > $1 | wc -l | read n; mv -- $1 ~/targetfile-$n.csv; } =(:)
```

Comment: Elegant solution (+1), I keep it for later, when I will learn zsh